# I can't deploy an Angular app to heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, npm, angular6

I am trying to deploy my angular 6 app on Heroku, 
After building the project and following all the steps of deploy, I get this result on heroku:

[image]

and th Heroku logs is :
[image]

when testing the deploy address, we get this result:

[image]

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: can you provide your Routes ?

Comment: Voilà le code sous server.js

Comment: const express = require('express');
const app = express();
// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
// Start the app by listening on the default
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});
// Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

Comment: do you run `ng build` before deploy to heroku?

Comment: yess, and it generates dist folder correctly

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));` try this

Comment: So my server.js file will be like that:                                                                           const express = require('express');
const app = express();      app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
//});
// Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

Comment: I get the Heroku interface, Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Comment: Heroku logs, showed this message:                                                               2018-07-04T10:51:04.262183+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cchain-project.herokuapp.com request_id=e567b9c4-dddc-45ad-a17e-45ae5baf3b84 fwd="196.203.248.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: @mintquan maybe the problem now, is related to the index.html file?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add wildcard `get` route in `server.js` as:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});
```

**Solution 2**

add one `index.php` file in dist folder add following code in it:

```
<?php header( 'Location: /index.html' ) ;  ?>
```

It will deploy your application.

Comment: Anshuman I used it, it helps, and the mesage was changed to :"Internal Server Error"

Comment: @ouijdenDhm where are you getting this error? Also can you post full error log.

Comment: @ouijdenDhm I have also added one more solution to deploy Angular on heroku. You can also try that.

Comment: 2018-07-04T14:17:18.265398+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-07-04T14:17:18.265401+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:9:28)2018-07-04T14:17:18.265404+00:00 app[web.1]:  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)2018-07-04T14:17:18.265409+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

Comment: 2018-07-04T14:17:18.265411+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-07-04T14:17:18.265406+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2018-07-04T14:17:18.265407+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
2018-07-04T14:17:18.265412+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-07-04T14:17:18.265414+00:00 app[web.1]:  at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
2018-07-04T14:17:18.594284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Comment: @ouijdenDhm can you share app.js? Also did you try second solution?

Comment: var express = require('express');
var app = express();                             
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

Comment: at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
2018-07-04T16:22:13.053387+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
2018-07-04T16:22:13.053389+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2018-07-04T16:22:13.053390+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
2018-07-04T16:22:13.053392+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

Comment: 2018-07-04T16:22:13.053394+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-07-04T16:22:13.053395+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-07-04T16:22:13.053397+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
2018-07-04T16:22:13.131656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Comment: 2018-07-04T16:22:14.439383+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cchain-redlean.herokuapp.com request_id=65f2bd4f-fcbe-496c-832f-41bd0b439a22 fwd="196.203.248.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: The detail of the actual situation are posted here: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186556/application-error-appearing-when-i-deploy-angular-app-with-heroku"

Comment: @ouijdenDhm you have not added `app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});` in `server.js`. Also in `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));` you have not used `/` i.e. it would be `/dist`

Comment: I may have my server.js look like this:                                                                    
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
// Start the app by listening on the default
app.get('/*', function(req, res) 
{ 
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html')); 
});
// Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);

Comment: yes,  I have this error appeared on Heroku logs                                                
   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/dist/index.html'

Comment: @ouijdenDhm OK, can you try `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));` i.e. remove `/dist`

Comment: @ouijdenDhm are you sure your build command is run so that it generates `dist` folder. I doubt.

Comment: yes, it doesn't generates dist folder.                                                                     
I tried herokuCLI command, under my project : heroku run bash --app <appName>    then  ls , and the dist doesn't appear. what should I do in this case, and how the build is successful?

Comment: Hello, my project generate now dist folder, but doesn't work, always I have the "error application" screen on Heroku. thank you for giving an advice, I need help in urgent please