# Application Error appearing when I deploy angular app with Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I've successfully deployed my angular6 application to heroku but unfortunately I'm getting the "An error occurred in the application and the page could not be served" page displaying.

here the package.json code sample:

```
  "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
"start": "node server.js",
"build": "ng build",
"build:prod": "npm run build",
"test": "ng test",
"test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
"lint": "ng lint",
"lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
"lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
"lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
"pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
"docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
"prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
"release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s",
"postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
```

},

When I run the app locally using npm start it runs fine.

My package.json file

{
  "name": "danoram-angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.3.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.3.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.16",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}

My server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
```

heroku logs:

2018-07-05T07:57:10.809919+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2018-07-05T07:57:10.809921+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
2018-07-05T07:57:10.809922+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
2018-07-05T07:57:10.809923+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-07-05T07:57:10.809925+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-07-05T07:57:10.809927+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
2018-07-05T07:57:11.005204+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-05T07:57:10.987769+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-07-05T07:57:12.647973+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cchain-redlean.herokuapp.com request_id=c9d781b1-89df-4b38-bd60-b81699303c1b fwd="196.203.248.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-05T07:57:13.158493+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cchain-redlean.herokuapp.com request_id=39b5588c-29b0-47b9-bacd-e93838e9ae16 fwd="196.203.248.245" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

The screenshot of the 
[image]

All help is appreciated!

Here question referred :[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163784/i-cant-deploy-an-angular-app-to-heroku/51165667#51165667)

Comment: Heroku logs( 1/2):                                                                                                  
   2018-07-05T09:17:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user dh.ouijden@gmail.com
2018-07-05T09:18:33.965137+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user dh.ouijden@gmail.com
2018-07-05T09:18:33.965137+00:00 app[api]: Deploy e76c0717 by user dh.ouijden@gmail.com
2018-07-05T09:18:34.824714+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-07-05T09:18:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

Comment: /app/server.js:3                                                                                                       app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));